# ".menu.opened" and ".opened", when should I use which?

Tags: css

I am learning the code in post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24811368/12214867)

```
    <style>
        .menu {
            display: none;   
        }

        .menu.opened {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
```

according to a comment on that post, the `.menu` part in `.menu.opened` is not needed technically, so I tried

```
    <style>
        .menu {
            display: none;   
        }

        .opened {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
```

works well just as before.

So, what is the difference between `.menu.opened` and `.opened`, when should I use which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.menu.opened` when your elements have both class `.menu` and `.opened` => use this if you want to css specify elements which have both class.

`.menu` `.opened` when your elements have class `.menu` or `.opened` => use this if you want to css all elements which have at least one of these class.

**The first**

> Example: `<x class="menu opened"></x>` => display block
>
> `<x class="menu"></x>` => display none
>
> `<x class="opened"></x>` =>no CSS

**The second**

> Example: `<x class="menu opened"></x>` => display block or none depend on priority (before, after class or !important)
>
> `<x class="menu"></x>` => display none
>
> `<x class="opened"></x>` => display block