# Call javascript function when page is completely loaded

Tags: javascript, load

I have a js function which needs to be called when the page is completely loaded. I tried calling the function on `body` as below

`onload="GridExpInfo_ClientInsert()"`

but it doesn't works as expected, it gets called before the page is fully loaded.

**UPDATE**

Code:

```
function GridExpInfo_ClientInsert() {
        var rowVal = "0";                  // assigned variable with value as 0
        for (i = 0; i < GridExpInfo.Rows.length; i++) {
            rowVal = i;                   // assigning values which always takes the value of i
            if (GridExpInfo.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value == "" || GridExpInfo.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value == "0") {
                document.getElementById('GridExpInfo_ob_GridExpInfoBodyContainer_ctl33_' + rowVal + '_ctl00_' + rowVal + '_Button1_' + rowVal + '').style.display = "none";
            }
            else {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [call a function after complete page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936816/call-a-function-after-complete-page-load)

Comment: Is some content in page is loaded through `AJAX` ?

Comment: it should do it, what's unexpected?

Comment: @Rayon: no, nothing is loaded thorugh `ajax`

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE] and tell us what part of the code is being loaded after the load event fires. We can't tell you how to make the code wait for something when we don't know what the something is.

Comment: @Quentin: My code works when I use it on other part. But When I am using it on load it doesn't works properly. I want to make it on page load. how to do that ?

Comment: @nad — The code you have should work "properly". Your question doesn't have enough information in it to tell why it does not. See my previous comment. You need a [MCVE]. You need to tell us what is loading after the load event fires.

Comment: @Quentin: What  happens is when the page is loaded, I get error as `GridExpInfo.Rows.length' is null or not an object`. So first time it gives me that error. I have updated the question

Comment: @Quentin: Sir, what else do you want. ?

Comment: A [MCVE]. That's a link. Click on it. Read it. (e.g. you haven't included any HTML. You haven't defined `GridExpInfo`)

Comment: @Quentin: I am unable to produce the problem on my side as the controls are asp.net. But if you understand what I am explaining, I m sure you will guide me to solve this problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127148/discussion-between-nad-and-quentin).

Comment: Why should we be able to solve your problem when you can't even demonstrate it?

Comment: @Quentin: You are correct, but see I have a grid what I want to show is when the page is loaded, I want to hide a button with some condition. I guess you can suggest me how to do this

Comment: Don't vaguely describe what you have. Show us a [MCVE]

Comment: @Quentin: sir, can u come on chat, I can explain you their better

Comment: No. Provide a [MCVE] in the question.