# Hide browser loading icon while waiting for async script tag

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I have a script included in my web site using `<script src="..." async></script>` so that it does not block rendering of the page. The script sometimes takes about 10 seconds to load. While the page is rendering almost immediately, the browser still shows the loading spinner in the tab until the script is loaded. Is there a way to define the page as being done even though the browser is still waiting for the script?

Comment: Could you load the script dynamically after the page has finished loading. See: [call a function after complete page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936816/call-a-function-after-complete-page-load).

Comment: @Tigger Yes, it HTML doesn't provide an option for that using JavaScript is fine.