# Mapbox queryRenderedFeatures on load

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I would like to use queryRenderedFeatures after the page loads in order to populate a list, but it seems to keep firing before the layer is loaded. I get the error message in the console below:

```
The layer 'Points' does not exist in the map's style and cannot be queried for features.
```

How can I query the layer after the feature is loaded? I tried following the suggestions in these answers but it keeps returning empty

[JavaScript that executes after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load?rq=1)

[call a function after complete page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936816/call-a-function-after-complete-page-load?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

This is what I have right now

```
map.on('load', function() {
  map.addLayer({
      'id': 'Points',
      'type': 'circle',
      'source': 'Points-45d56v',
      'source-layer': 'Points-45d56v',
      'layout': {
          'visibility': 'visible',
      },
      'paint': {
        'circle-radius': 6,
        'circle-color': 'red'
      }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures({layers:['Points']});
  console.log(features);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I got the following code from the Github link in the previous answer, which worked for me:

```
map.addLayer(...) // make your change
map.on('render', afterChangeComplete); // warning: this fires many times per second!

function afterChangeComplete () {
  if (!map.loaded()) { return } // still not loaded; bail out.

  // now that the map is loaded, it's safe to query the features:
  map.queryRenderedFeatures(...);

  map.off('render', afterChangeComplete); // remove this handler now that we're done.
}
```

Be sure to put it in the same `map.on('load', function() {});` as the layer to be queried.

Answer (score 3):

From https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4222#issuecomment-279446075:

You can check `map.loaded()` (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#loaded) to determine whether the map is loaded and it's safe to query the features.

For example code see the linked issue comment on GitHub.