# Conditional formatting html table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Using only javascript (not jquery, etc) set background-color for html table row based on the value of a cell value in table column. If value in 'Results' column equals 'Success' then row is 'green' if value is 'Fail' then row is 'red'.

Background: 
-modifying python code that generates html with table, already added 'sort on click' function
-tried several options for conditionally formatting, none successfully
-true newbie, so dropping all sample code
-focus on function resultFormatting at end of code

```js
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  dir = "asc";
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      switchcount++;
    } else {
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

function resultFormatting() {
  ('tr').each(function() {
    var col_val = $(this).find('td.eq(4)').text();
    if (col_val == "Success") {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('bad');
    }
  });
});
.selected {
  background-color: green;
}
.bad {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
}

th {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p style="font-size:30px">
    Total tests: 10. Failed tests: 2. Skipped tests: 0.<br>
  </p>
  <p style="font-size:30px">
    Report test time 0:00:00<br>
  </p>
  <table border="1" id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Facility</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Test_group</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Test_number</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(3)">Description</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(4)">Result</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(5)">Execution_time</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(6)">Information</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(7)">Output</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td>Room</td>
        <td>468</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>Horse</td>
        <td>Success</td>
        <td>0:14:39</td>
        <td>Brown</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Den</td>
        <td>288</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mule</td>
        <td>Success</td>
        <td>0:00:21</td>
        <td>Brown</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Den</td>
        <td>660</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Horse</td>
        <td>Success</td>
        <td>0:05:47</td>
        <td>Brown</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Patio</td>
        <td>148</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Pig</td>
        <td>Fail</td>
        <td>0:14:34</td>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Patio</td>
        <td>386</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Horse</td>
        <td>Fail</td>
        <td>0:13:07</td>
        <td>Brown</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room</td>
        <td>238</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Pig</td>
        <td>Success</td>
        <td>0:13:17</td>
        <td>Brown</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Den</td>
        <td>988</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Dog</td>
        <td>Success</td>
        <td>0:05:13</td>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room</td>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>Mule</td>
        <td>Success</td>
        <td>0:05:32</td>
        <td>Purple</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room</td>
        <td>973</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Pig</td>
        <td>Success</td>
        <td>0:00:06</td>
        <td>Purple</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Shower</td>
        <td>547</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>Horse</td>
        <td>Success</td>
        <td>0:09:26</td>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: What is `('tr').each` supposed to be doing if you're not wanting to use a library? Looks like some typo.

Comment: Also, you have CSS in a `<script>` tag.

Comment: If you have python code generating the HTML table, then why not just add the appropriate class to the corresponding `<tr>` element?

Comment: @SunnyPatel - of all the code I researched and tried this snippet seemed the most promising; granted python code would likely be more efficient, however I'd like to find a javascript solution since I was successful at sorting table columns with js only

Comment: Since they're not really related, why not post the same question with your Python code? I'll see about answering both.

Comment: @SunnyPatel - I added the python code (sorry could not add as additional snippet tagged as python; i can make new question if that is best.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. Add a new question based on Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a pure JS solution to this (negating the fact that you had tried to implement a jQuery solution), just use the following:

```
function resultFormatting() {
  var rows = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName('tr');
  for (var i = 0; i < rows[0].children.length && rows[0].children[i].innerHTML !== "Result"; i++);
  for (var j = 1; j < rows.length; j++) {
    rows[j].classList.add(rows[j].children[i].innerHTML === "Success" ? 'selected' : 'bad');
  }
};
```

This gets all the rows in your `myTable`. Searches the first heading row for "Result", incase you wanted to reorder the columns and saves that index to `i`.

Then the code goes through the remaining rows to add one of the two classes you had partially implemented for the rows based on the value of the `i`'th column's value.

Here's the full snippet:

```js
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  dir = "asc";
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      switchcount++;
    } else {
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

function resultFormatting() {
  var rows = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName('tr');
  for (var i = 0; i < rows[0].children.length && rows[0].children[i].innerHTML !== "Result"; i++);
  for (var j = 1; j < rows.length; j++) {
    rows[j].classList.add(rows[j].children[i].innerHTML === "Success" ? 'selected' : 'bad');
  }
};

resultFormatting();
```

```css
td {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
}

th {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background-color: green;
}

.bad {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p style="font-size:30px">
    Total tests: 10. Failed tests: 2. Skipped tests: 0.<br>
  </p>
  <p style="font-size:30px">
    Report test time 0:00:00<br>
  </p>
  <table border="1" id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Facility</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Test_group</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Test_number</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(3)">Description</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(4)">Result</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(5)">Execution_time</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(6)">Information</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(7)">Output</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td>Room</td>
        <td>468</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>Horse</td>
        <td>Success</td>
        <td>0:14:39</td>
        <td>Brown</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Den</td>
        <td>288</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mule</td>
        <td>Success</td>
        <td>0:00:21</td>
        <td>Brown</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Den</td>
        <td>660</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Horse</td>
        <td>Success</td>
        <td>0:05:47</td>
        <td>Brown</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Patio</td>
        <td>148</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Pig</td>
        <td>Fail</td>
        <td>0:14:34</td>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Patio</td>
        <td>386</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Horse</td>
        <td>Fail</td>
        <td>0:13:07</td>
        <td>Brown</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room</td>
        <td>238</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Pig</td>
        <td>Success</td>
        <td>0:13:17</td>
        <td>Brown</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Den</td>
        <td>988</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Dog</td>
        <td>Success</td>
        <td>0:05:13</td>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room</td>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>Mule</td>
        <td>Success</td>
        <td>0:05:32</td>
        <td>Purple</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room</td>
        <td>973</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Pig</td>
        <td>Success</td>
        <td>0:00:06</td>
        <td>Purple</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Shower</td>
        <td>547</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>Horse</td>
        <td>Success</td>
        <td>0:09:26</td>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: wow, not sure how you determined I tried jquery tablesorter, but I did...I've tried several ways to incorporate the code, with no success, I will keep trying, since I believe I follow the flow...

Comment: @fjm Again, a python solution is the best. And from your edit, I can tell you right away how to fix it if you write up a question with that info.

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51600410/conditional-format-html-table-rows-with-python

Comment: Please accept if this worked out for you. You'll just need to execute that function after the [table is loaded into the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936816/call-a-function-after-complete-page-load).

Comment: added **document.getElementById("myTable").addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", resultFormatting);** preceding function, tried several syntax from link provided and other sources, to no avail.

Comment: Can just add `resultFormatting();` to execute in a `<script>` tag by itself before you close the `</body>` tag.

Comment: simple enough, tried and tried, but function does not execute, placed following function between    <script> </script> tags and just before     </body> tag; thank you for your assistance

Comment: Sorry, I realized after more testing that there was issues in the code. I've edited and updated my answer.

Comment: I've edited function as noted and tripled checked that I made the changes, the function is invoked as early described, the CSS .selected & .bad are in place as they were for the Python solution, so I think that part is good, but still no row painting...I will keep trying to understand the function to troubleshoot too.

Comment: ahhh...yes it does....ok, so I'll review all of the code and see what I've done wrong, once I have made whatever needed changes I'll mark as answered, many thanks Sunny

Comment: thank you, I finally decided to simply delete and rewrite the function...and then all is good, thank you very much.