# I want to execute JavaScript code after few seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript code which shows kind of seal on site, here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="foo" src="https://www.rapidscansecure.com/siteseal/siteseal.js?code=[companyidcode]" ></script>
```

this impact on website insight score, I just want to execute this after few second of page load completed.

defer and async already used and not working

Comment: Try using async and deffer in that
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808109/script-tag-async-defer

Comment: I have already used defer and async, but does not work

Answer (score 1):

Add [defer](https://javascript.info/script-async-defer) attribute to the `<script>`.

The script is downloaded in background. And the script is executed once the browser is free after all the HTML document has been parsed.

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="foo" src="https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/" defer></script>
```

Edit: The script is still executed before the `DOMContentLoaded`, but after DOM parsing.

Comment: This is not an accurate answer, because defer download the script parallelly and run after the dom is parsed and before `DOMContentLoaded` event. Browser is free when everything is done in the background and dom parsed and all scripts loaded and executed.

Comment: I have already used defer and async, but does not work

Answer (score 1):

Try Using document.onload = function ..

See this Question [How to make JavaScript execute after page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/how-to-make-javascript-execute-after-page-load)

[execute function after complete page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936816/execute-function-after-complete-page-load)

Comment: Ok, I will try this. Thanks!